# RabbitMQ Manual ACK on c# client

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

I'm trying to use a manual ACK on a very simple console application, but I can't make it work.

On the sender, I have the following code:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                         durable: true,
                         exclusive: false,
                         autoDelete: false,
                         arguments: null);

    var message = GetMessage(args);
    var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

    channel.ConfirmSelect();
    channel.BasicAcks += (sender, e) =>
    {
        Console.Write("ACK received");
    };

    var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();

    channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "",
                         routingKey: "task_queue",
                         basicProperties: properties,
                         body: body);

    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
}

Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
Console.ReadLine();
```

On the receiver I have the following code:

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
{
    channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                         durable: true,
                         exclusive: false,
                         autoDelete: false,
                         arguments: null);

    channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);
    channel.ConfirmSelect();

    Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");

    var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
    consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
    {
        var body = ea.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

        int dots = message.Split('.').Length - 1;
        Thread.Sleep(dots * 1000);

        channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        Console.WriteLine(" [x] Done");
    };
    channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue",
                         noAck: false,
                         consumer: consumer);

    Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What I expect is that the event `BasicAcks` on the sender is fired when I call `channel.BasicAck()` on the receiver, but that event is being fired when the message is delivered to the client, before `consumer.Received`.

Is what I'm expecting the correct behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your expectation is not correct. `BasicAcks` is about [publisher confirms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html), not about ack from receiver. So you publish a message to broker and *broker* (so, RabbitMQ itself) will ack or nack (negative acknowledge) you when it handles this message (for example - when it will write it to disk for persistent messages, or when in puts it in queue). Note that no receiver is involved here - it's entirely between publisher and RabbitMQ.

Now when you Ack message at receiver - that's again only between receiver and RabbitMQ - you tell rabbit that message is processed and can be safely deleted. This is done to handle situations when receiver crashes during processing - then rabbit will be able to deliver this message to the next receiver (if any).

Note that the whole purpose of such arcitecture is to separate publishers and receivers - they should not be dependent on each other.

If you have one receiver (there can be many) and you want to ensure it processed your message - use RPC pattern: send message and wait for another message back from this receiver.

Answer (score 3):

Consumer:

```
consumer.Received += async (model, ea) =>
{
    var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

    int dots = message.Split('.').Length - 1;
    await Task.Delay(2000);

    channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
    Console.WriteLine(" [x] Done");
};
```