# rabbitmq, python - ack consumer program example

Tags: python, rabbitmq

I'm looking for a basic Rabbitmq ack consumer program in python. So far, I have the basic ack producer program. But I don't know whether it is correct.

**producer.py**

```py
import pika, socket

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxx', '1234')
hostname = socket.gethostname()
parameters = 
pika.ConnectionParameters(host=socket.gethostbyname(hostname), 
port=5672, virtual_host='/', credentials=credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

msg_props = pika.BasicProperties()
msg_props.content_type = "text/plain"

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')
if channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello 
World!', properties=msg_props):
     print ("Message Acknowledged")
else:
     print ("Message Lost")

print("[x] Sent 'Hello World!'")
connection.close()
```

**consumer.py**

```py
import pika, socket

credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('xxxx', '1234')
hostname = socket.gethostname()
parameters = 
pika.ConnectionParameters(host=socket.gethostbyname(hostname), 
port=5672, virtual_host='/', credentials=credentials)

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello')

def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    print(" [x] Received %r" % body)
    channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)

channel.basic_consume(queue='hello', on_message_callback=callback, 
auto_ack=False)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')
channel.start_consuming()
```

```
>python consumer.py

 [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C
 [x] Received b'Hello World!'


>python producer.py

 Message Lost
 [x] Sent 'Hello World!'
```

Output:

```
Though the message is received at the consumer.py program, the delivery 
note at producer.py says, "Message Lost", but the note should be "Message Acknowledged".
```

What is the correct consumer and producer ack program in python for rabbitmq?

Comment: Which python version are you using? It worked perfectly in python 3.6.

Comment: python 3.6, Can you please post your consumer program?

Comment: Sorry, pika's basic_publish returns None, so you will always get "Message lost". SOMETIMES it raises an error. You need to run the publishing with confirmations enabled, pika method confirm_delivery, for verifying publishing. Check https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days and days of research, to get the desired result, I finally found this, from the link - [RabbitMQ Manual ACK on c# client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307437/rabbitmq-manual-ack-on-c-sharp-client)

Answered by @Evk,
"... BasicAcks is about publisher confirms, not about ack from receiver. So you publish a message to broker and broker (so, RabbitMQ itself) will ack or nack (negative acknowledge) you when it handles this message (for example - when it will write it to disk for persistent messages, or when in puts it in queue). Note that no receiver is involved here - it's entirely between publisher and RabbitMQ.

Now when you Ack message at receiver - that's again only between receiver and RabbitMQ - you tell rabbit that message is processed and can be safely deleted. This is done to handle situations when receiver crashes during processing - then rabbit will be able to deliver this message to the next receiver (if any).

Note that the whole purpose of such arcitecture is to separate publishers and receivers - they should not be dependent on each other.

If you have one receiver (there can be many) and you want to ensure it processed your message - use RPC pattern: send message and wait for another message back from this receiver."

Comment: I am afraid that this is mixing several topics. pika basic_ack is for consumer confirmation, and there is pika confirm_delivery for publish confirmations. See rabbitmq.com/confirms.html .