# how to delete a response queue with rabbitmq?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Consider this rabbitmq replyto queue mechanism where only 1 message is retrieved, sent back to a client, and then the generated (auto-delete) queue must be deleted.

```
    string startResponseConsumer(IModel? channel)
    {
        string replyQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            if (!callbackMapper.TryRemove(ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId, out var tcs))
                return;

            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            tcs.TrySetResult(response);
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);

        return replyQueueName;
    }
```

It works, messages responses are sent back to the client, but the queue is not deleted. After 10 calls this is whats shown in the console.

[image]

So every time this is called, a queue is added. They are only removed on exit, I guess when the channel is Disposed.

But this is a service, which must be up all the time and not accumulate queues forever. So I added channel.Close() in the received event.

```
    string startResponseConsumer(IModel? channel)
    {
        string replyQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            if (!callbackMapper.TryRemove(ea.BasicProperties.CorrelationId, out var tcs))
                return;

            var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
            var response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            tcs.TrySetResult(response);

            // added this to have the queue removed
            if (channel != default)
            {
                channel.Close();
                channel = default;
            }
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);

        return replyQueueName;
    }
```

This is not thread safe, the channel that is created for every thread gets closed before all messages are processed.

Is there a correct way to have an autodelete queue removed after receiving a message?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37307437/rabbitmq-manual-ack-on-c-sharp-client
This might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

When everything is as normal and the reply message gets an ACK the conumer closes its channel.

```
        string replyQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare().QueueName;

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);

        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            if (channel != default)
            {
                channel.Close();
                channel = default;
            }
        };

        channel.BasicConsume(replyQueueName, true, consumer);
```

But when the reply message is not sent for whatever reason (eg service down) a timer is started causing a delayed execution of 30 second of channel close

DelayedExecution just uses a System.Threading.Timer.

```
DelayedExecution.Go(() => { 
        if (channel != null && channel.IsOpen) { channel.Close(); } 
}, 30000);
```

Option number two would be to set the x-expires header on the queue level on the reply queue.

```
Dictionary<string, object> args = new() { { "x-expires", 3600000 } };

string replyQueueName = channel.QueueDeclare(arguments: args).QueueName;
```